# В чём ошибка при сборке ядра embedded Linux?

Tags: linux, c, kernel, makefile, embedded

Господа, столкнулся с довольно специфичной проблемой: пытаюсь с помощью buildroot собрать линуксовое ядро для одной железки. В процессе сборки получаю следующую ошибку:

```
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      mm/ksm.o
  LD      sound/built-in.o
  CC      kernel/smp.o
In file included from include/linux/linkage.h:6:0,
                 from include/linux/preempt.h:9,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:50,
                 from include/linux/mmzone.h:7,
                 from include/linux/gfp.h:5,
                 from include/linux/mm.h:9,
                 from mm/ksm.c:18:
include/linux/export.h:57:2: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘extern’
  extern typeof(sym) sym;     \
```

В файле же export.h этот фрагмент используется в макросе:

```
/* For every exported symbol, place a struct in the __ksymtab section */
#define __EXPORT_SYMBOL(sym, sec)           \
  extern typeof(sym) sym;                   \
  __CRC_SYMBOL(sym, sec)                    \
  static const char __kstrtab_##sym[]       \
  __attribute__((section("__ksymtab_strings"), aligned(1))) \
  = VMLINUX_SYMBOL_STR(sym);                \
  extern const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym;    \
  __visible const struct kernel_symbol __ksymtab_##sym  \
  __used                            \
  __attribute__((section("___ksymtab" sec "+" #sym), unused))   \
  = { (unsigned long)&sym, __kstrtab_##sym }
```

Я не вижу в нём ничего криминального. Более того -- это стандартный макрос ядра. С чем связана ошибка при сборке?

Comment: Ну ошибка-то наверное находится **до** использования этого макроса в том файле, в котором он используется. То есть сюда смотреть бесполезно - тут все в порядке. Надо смотреть `mm.h` и, скорее всего, далее вверх по цепочке включений. Более того, ошибку мог привнести предыдущий хедер в списке.

Comment: Сборка "чистая"?  Конфигурация ядра не перемудрённая вами? Ещё момент, вы уверены, что файл, в который вы смотрите, это тот же самый файл, на который ругается компилятор?

Comment: @AnT, вся эта цепочка сводится к одной-единственной ошибке -- попытке импортировать содержимое export.h. ksm.c импортирует mm.h, тот -- gfp.h и т.д. до export.h, в котором определён макрос.

В самом же файле export.h до определения макроса __EXPORT_SYMBOL(sym, sec)  идёт определение другого макроса. Тоже вполне безобидного:

`#define __CRC_SYMBOL(sym, sec)     \
extern __visible void *__crc_##sym __attribute__((weak));  \
static const unsigned long __kcrctab_##sym  \
__used       \
__attribute__((section("___kcrctab" sec "+" #sym), unused)) \
= (unsigned long) &__crc_##sym;`

Comment: @0andriy, да, вполне уверен. Сборка, если что, не вполне чистая, я пытаюсь использовать ядро, выдранное из android-проекта, предоставленного вендором (только там есть нужные мне драйвера). Однако конкретно этот файл export.h полностью идентичен аналогичному из ванильного ядра.

Comment: А само по себе ядро собирается (традиционным способом, без всяких Android или Buildroot окружений)?

Comment: [этим коммитом](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/f235541699bcf14fb8be797c6bc1d7106df0eb64) `__EXPORT_SYMBOL` был переименован в `___EXPORT_SYMBOL` (с тремя подчёркиваниями), а под старым именем `__EXPORT_SYMBOL` теперь другой макрос. возможно, у вас несогласованы версия исходников программы linux и того стороннего, что вы добавили.

Comment: @0andriy, проверил -- не собирается. Выдаёт ошибку вида `In file included from include/linux/perf_event.h:47:0,
                 from kernel/sched/core.c:41:
kernel/sched/core.c: In function ‘preempt_count_add’:
include/linux/ftrace.h:632:36: error: calling ‘__builtin_return_address’ with a nonzero argument is unsafe [-Werror=frame-address]
 #  define ftrace_return_address(n) __builtin_return_address(n)`

Comment: Слишком новый компилятор для достаточно старого ядра?